# Best practices for the order of joined columns in a sql join?

Tags: sql

There's a big discussion going on at my office on the order of the joined columns in a sql join. I'm finding it hard explaining it so I'll just present the two sql statements. Which one is better taking into account sql best practices?

```
SELECT a.Au_id 
FROM   AUTHORS a 
       INNER JOIN TITLEAUTHOR ta 
         ON a.Au_id = ta.Au_id 
       INNER JOIN TITLES t 
         ON ta.Title_id = t.Title_id 
WHERE  t.Title LIKE ‘%Computer%’
```

OR

```
SELECT a.Au_id 
FROM   AUTHORS a 
       INNER JOIN TITLEAUTHOR ta 
         ON ta.Au_id = a.Au_id
       INNER JOIN TITLES t 
         ON t.Title_id = ta.Title_id
WHERE  t.Title LIKE ‘%Computer%’
```

So, in a join, in the ON part, does it matter whether you write `A.x = B.y or B.y = A.x`?

Comment: I would use the same order as the `JOINs`, so version 1. Just because it's more readable. By the way, in .NET's `LINQ` (all providers) it's even mandatory.

Comment: Since there's no functional difference, it just boils down to a matter of taste. In that sense: I prefer version 2.

Comment: From a purely aesthetical point of view, I'd prefer version 2, but I guess this comment gets just as many downvotes as it gets upvotes.

Comment: It's doesn't matter since SQL-Server will optimize it, but you could make it matter: Add `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` to the query. General rule of thumb, JOIN order should be with table of least records on top, and most records last. The order in the `ON`-clause is (obviously) a matter of taste.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best practice here is to choose one and stick with it **within the team**. Personally, I prefer the `FROM a JOIN b ON b.col = a.col` because it seems cleaner to me.

Comment: Why is it cleaner to reverse the order?

Comment: YES! In the absence of a best practice, the next best practice is _be consistent_. Although I really don't think it's too important in an ON clause.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Why don't I like beer (sadly) ? Just a matter of taste

Comment: @ThomasRuiz: consistency is not a matter of taste and `a join b on b = a` is not a consistent order, is it? However, i agree that it's most impoortant that the whole team uses the same way.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, it seems consistent to me, as you are joining `b` to `a`.

Comment: @ThomasRuiz: that's not the point, if `a=b` then `b=a`, so both tables are joined with each other. It seems to be really a matter of taste, so it doesn't make much sense to debate. I prefer `a JOIN b ON a.col=b.col` and `b JOIN a ON b.col=a.col`.

Comment: So there's no 'official' best practices when it comes to sql? Well, maybe there is, but not concerning my question it seems...

Comment: @ThomasRuiz How can you not like beer? ;-) Have you tried Belgian beers?

Comment: @LievenCardoen, I think there are some related to specific dbas. Google might be the best answer I can give you for those :) (and yeah, I tried a lot of different beers, I guess i'm just unlucky)

Answer (score 3):

SQL was designed to be readable as usual English text. In a usual text, when we want to specify any mentioned object, we say something like "An object. This object is like that object, this object is related to that object, and this object has those properties." We do not say "That object is like this object, and that object is related this object, and those properties have this object".

So, when we adding records of TableB to query from TableA, we need to specify what a record from TableB must have to satisfy the current record from TableA. So we must say "we need that records from TableB, which have an id, equal to TableA.ID", i.e., `FROM TableA a JOIN TableB b ON b.col = a.col`. We must write exactly in this order, to provide easy reading and understanding of this relation.

And I'm very very sad, that almost all SQL documentation does not provide any kind of reasoning to go one or another direction in this question, but have a lot of examples of wrong writing equation arguments in order of presenting of tables in a query.

Comment: In another point of view, in English texts we can use definite and indefinite articles, to mention what we already know, and what does not know yet and wish to specify in the sentence. This allows do not depend on the order of items in the sentence. So order is not such critical to native English speakers as an articles. For example, Russian language does not have an articles, and we use order in sentence or intonation to note, what is new in the sentence and what is already known in the context. But in SQL we also have not the articles!

Answer (score 1):

I have always used option 1 and that is also the way that orcale teach it on their SQL and PL/SQL course.

On the subject of best practice though,

One thing you have used that oracle also teach is the 1 or 2 letter table aliases.. Although this can seem like a great idea at the time and it makes writing the statement / procedure / function allot easier (at the time) it can be difficult to then come back and look at the same piece of code at a later date.

e.g.
We have many PL/SQL functions that are looking at / pulling data from tens of tables and while the aliases are fresh in your mind , great, but come back to the same code in a few years and it can get sticky.

I'm not saying don't use table aliases but i always try and avoid the 1 or 2 letter ones that allot of places / people teach.

(Not quite on the topic of joins only but on the topic of best practice)

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't make a difference, the database query optimiser will decide on the best way to execute the query regardless of how you order your join conditions, or even your where clauses.

The way the oracle optimiser handles joins is explained in quite a bit of detail at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/optimops.htm#39473.

Comment: DoctorMick, question isn't about performance, it's about coding conventions and best practices.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to the below link, where it concludes that the order in ON clause doesn't affect the result.
The database optimizer will decide the best way and plan to execute the query.

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/02/29/60542.aspx

Comment: Hi SahuKahn, my question was not about performance, but just about coding conventions.