# Order of keys in the LEFT JOIN condition

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

What happens when we reverse the order of keys in the LEFT JOIN condition?

Ideal SQL left join syntax for joining two tables is

```
select fields 
from tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB 
ON tableA.key = tableB.key
```

Flipped order of join condition

```
select fields 
from tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB 
ON tableB.key = tableA.key  -- (order flipped)
```

Will these queries produce different set of results?

Comment: same thing no diff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` is not commutative, you can't switch arguments: `tableA LEFT JOIN tableB` is equivalent to `tableB RIGHT JOIN tableA`, and different from `tableB LEFT JOIN tableA`.

`==` is commutative, you *can* switch arguments: `tableA.key = tableB.key` is equivalent to `tableB.key = tableA.key`.

Answer (score 6):

You will get the same results. The on clause just evaluates to true or false; the order does not matter.

Only the position of the tables themselves matter. e.g. reversing table order as below would give different results.

```
select fields 
from tableB 
LEFT JOIN tableA
ON tableA.key = tableB.key
```

Answer (score 0):

No any difference, except readability of the query.

SQL was designed to be readable as usual English text. In a usual text, when we want to specify any mentioned object, we say something like "An object. This object is like that object, this object is related to that object, and this object has those properties." We do not say "That object is like this object, to that object related this object and those properties have this object".

So, when we adding records of TableB to query from TableA, we need to specify what must have a record from TableB to satisfy current record from TableA. So we must say, wee need that records from TableB, which have an id, equal to TableA.ID. TableB.id = TableA.id. We must write exactly in this order, to provide easy reading and understanding of this relation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428427/best-practices-for-the-order-of-joined-columns-in-a-sql-join/62287985 is a similar question