# Order of columns in INNER JOIN condition affects the performance badly

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have two tables which links to each other like this:

Table `answered_questions` with the following columns and indexes:

- `id`: primary key
- `taken_test_id`: integer (foreign key)
- `question_id`: integer (foreign key, links to another table called `questions`)
- `indexes`: (taken_test_id, question_id)

Table `taken_tests`

- `id`: primary key
- `user_id`: (foreign key, links to table Users)
- indexes: `user_id` column

**First query (with EXPLAIN ANALYZE output):**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT 
  "answered_questions".* 
FROM 
  "answered_questions" 
  INNER JOIN "taken_tests" ON "answered_questions"."taken_test_id" = "taken_tests"."id" 
WHERE 
  "taken_tests"."user_id" = 1;
```

**Output:**

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..116504.61 rows=1472 width=61) (actual time=0.025..2.208 rows=653 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using index_taken_tests_on_user_id on taken_tests  (cost=0.43..274.18 rows=91 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.483 rows=371 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (user_id = 1)
   ->  Index Scan using index_answered_questions_on_taken_test_id_and_question_id on answered_questions  (cost=0.56..1273.61 rows=365 width=61) (actual time=0.00
2..0.003 rows=2 loops=371)
         Index Cond: (taken_test_id = taken_tests.id)
 Planning time: 0.276 ms
 Execution time: 2.365 ms
(7 rows)
```

**Another query (this is generated automatically by Rails when using `joins` method in ActiveRecord)**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT 
  "answered_questions".* 
FROM 
  "answered_questions" 
  INNER JOIN "taken_tests" ON "taken_tests"."id" = "answered_questions"."taken_test_id" 
WHERE 
  "taken_tests"."user_id" = 1;
```

And here is the output

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..116504.61 rows=1472 width=61) (actual time=23.611..1257.807 rows=653 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using index_taken_tests_on_user_id on taken_tests  (cost=0.43..274.18 rows=91 width=4) (actual time=10.451..71.474 rows=371 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (user_id = 1)
   ->  Index Scan using index_answered_questions_on_taken_test_id_and_question_id on answered_questions  (cost=0.56..1273.61 rows=365 width=61) (actual time=2.07
1..3.195 rows=2 loops=371)
         Index Cond: (taken_test_id = taken_tests.id)
 Planning time: 0.302 ms
 Execution time: 1258.035 ms
(7 rows)
```

The only difference is the order of columns in the **INNER JOIN** condition. In the first query, it is `ON "answered_questions"."taken_test_id" = "taken_tests"."id"` while in the second query, it is `ON "taken_tests"."id" = "answered_questions"."taken_test_id"`. But the query time is hugely different.

Do you have any idea why this happens? I read some articles and it says that the order of columns in JOIN condition should not affect the execution time (ex: [Best practices for the order of joined columns in a sql join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428427/best-practices-for-the-order-of-joined-columns-in-a-sql-join))

I am using Postgres 9.6. There are more than 40 million rows in `answered_questions` table and more than 3 million rows in `taken_tests` table

## Update 1:

When I ran the EXPLAIN with `(analyze true, verbose true, buffers true)`, I got a much better result for the second query (quite similar to the first query)

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE TRUE, VERBOSE TRUE, BUFFERS TRUE) 
SELECT
  "answered_questions".* 
FROM
  "answered_questions"
  INNER JOIN "taken_tests" ON "taken_tests"."id" = "answered_questions"."taken_test_id" 
WHERE
  "taken_tests"."user_id" = 1;
```

**Output**

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..116504.61 rows=1472 width=61) (actual time=0.030..2.192 rows=653 loops=1)
   Output: answered_questions.id, answered_questions.question_id, answered_questions.answer_text, answered_questions.created_at, answered_questions.updated_at, a
nswered_questions.taken_test_id, answered_questions.correct, answered_questions.answer
   Buffers: shared hit=1986
   ->  Index Scan using index_taken_tests_on_user_id on public.taken_tests  (cost=0.43..274.18 rows=91 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.441 rows=371 loops=1)
         Output: taken_tests.id
         Index Cond: (taken_tests.user_id = 1)
         Buffers: shared hit=269
   ->  Index Scan using index_answered_questions_on_taken_test_id_and_question_id on public.answered_questions  (cost=0.56..1273.61 rows=365 width=61) (actual ti
me=0.002..0.003 rows=2 loops=371)
         Output: answered_questions.id, answered_questions.question_id, answered_questions.answer_text, answered_questions.created_at, answered_questions.updated
_at, answered_questions.taken_test_id, answered_questions.correct, answered_questions.answer
         Index Cond: (answered_questions.taken_test_id = taken_tests.id)
         Buffers: shared hit=1717
 Planning time: 0.238 ms
 Execution time: 2.335 ms
```

Comment: You consistently get this difference in performance on multiple tests typing each of these in by hand?

Comment: Yup, tested and compared them again and again, still the same result

Comment: Can you use `explain(analyze true, verbose true, buffers true)` ? And share again the result

Comment: @dwir182 I updated the output in my question, it seems to run much faster when I add those options

Comment: The only explanation that does not resort to magic and UFOs that I can imagine is that in the slow case some of the 1717 blocks from the inner loop have to be read from disk (a caching effect). But that fllatly contradicts your claim that the effect is persistent. Can you still reproduce it?

Comment: After I ran EXPLAIN  with (analyze true, buffers true), it seems the query became much faster (I ran it many times and it was still fast). But if I wait for a while and re-run the query, it is slow again. Weird!

Comment: Have you done a VACUUM ANALYZE recently? This sort of difference should only occur if there are no statistics or they are badly out of date.

Comment: Check this out - https://sqlperformance.com/2018/07/performance-myths/query-result-cache.  The subsequent executions may be faster based on the table already being in memory.  The first execution will be slower than subsequent executions.  Experts - please tell me if I am barking up the wrong  tree here.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/explicit-joins.html) explains *join order*.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the initial `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` statement results -- the queries are resulting in the equivalent query plan and are executed exactly the same.

The difference comes from the very same unit's execution time:

`->  Index Scan using index_taken_tests_on_user_id on taken_tests  (cost=0.43..274.18 rows=91 width=4) (`**actual time=0.014..0.483**`rows=371 loops=1)`

and

`->  Index Scan using index_taken_tests_on_user_id on taken_tests  (cost=0.43..274.18 rows=91 width=4) (`**actual time=10.451..71.474**`rows=371 loops=1)`

As the commenters already pointed out (see documentation links in the wuestion comments), the query plan for an inner join is expected to be the same regardless of the table order. It is ordered based on the query planner decisions. This means that you should really look at other performance-optimisation parts of the query execution. One of those would be memory used for caching (`SHARED BUFFER`). It looks like the query results would depend a lot on whether this data has already been loaded into memory. Just as you have noticed -- the query execution time grows after you have waited some time. This clearly indicates the cache expiry issue more than the plan problem.
Increasing the size of the shared buffers may help resolve it, but the initial execution of the query will always take longer -- this is just your disk access speed.

For more hints on memory configuration of Pg database see here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

**Note**: VACUUM or ANALYZE commands will be unlikely to help here. Both queries are using the same plan already. Keep in mind, though, that due to PostgreSQL transaction isolation mechanism (MVCC) it may have to read the underlying table rows to validate that they are still visible to the current transaction after getting the results from the index. This could be improved by updating the visibility map (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/storage-vm.html), which is done during vacuuming.